# Regular expression with hash keys and values

Tags: perl

I am trying to check if the certain terms appear in the hash key, if they I tag them with the hash values. My code identifies an exact match but fails for terms that are slightly different. Also for the exact match the code tags the matched term with all values instead of the relevant one.

```
%Drugs = ('tamoxifen' => tablet,
        'docotaxel' => capsule,
        '5-hydroxycin' => IDK,);

$sentence="tamoxifen 4-hydroxytamoxifen tamoxifen-incoded pre-docotaxel Drugs";
@sentence=split/ /,$sentence;
@array=();
foreach $word(@sentence)
{
    chomp $word;
    for $keys(keys %Drugs)
    {
        if($Drugs{$word})
        {
            $term="<$Drugs{$keys}>$word<$Drugs{$keys}>";
            push(@array,$term);
        }
        elsif($word=~/.*$Drugs{$keys}$/i)
        {
            $term="<$Drugs{$keys}>$word<$Drugs{$keys}>";
            push(@array,$term);
        }
    }
    foreach $Bio(@array)
    {
        print "$Bio\n";
    }
```

I want the output Sentence:

```
<tablet>tamoxifen</tablet> <tablet>4-hydroxytamoxifen</tablet> <tablet>tamoxifen-incoded<tablet> <capsule>pre-docotaxel<capsule> Drugs.(Here Drugs didn't match and hence it is left untagged)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were checking for an exact match, but based on what you expected you had to regex your $word against the $key

try this - >

```
%Drugs = ('tamoxifen' => tablet,
        'docotaxel' => capsule,
        '5-hydroxycin' => IDK,);

$sentence="tamoxifen 4-hydroxytamoxifen tamoxifen-incoded pre-docotaxel Drugs";
@sentence=split/ /,$sentence;
@array=();
foreach $word(@sentence)
{
    chomp $word;
    for $keys(keys %Drugs)
    {
        if($word=~/.*$keys$/i)#Changed this
        {
            $term="<$Drugs{$keys}>$word<$Drugs{$keys}>";
            push(@array,$term);
        }
        elsif($word=~/.*$Drugs{$keys}$/i)
        {
            $term="<$Drugs{$keys}>$word<$Drugs{$keys}>";
            push(@array,$term);
        }
    }
}
foreach $Bio(@array)
  {
     print "$Bio\n";
  }
```

**UPDATE**

---

Based on the new requirements

```
%Drugs = ('tamoxifen' => tablet,
        'docotaxel' => capsule,
        '5-hydroxycin' => IDK,);

$sentence="tamoxifen 4-hydroxytamoxifen tamoxifen-incoded pre-docotaxel Drugs";
@sentence=split/ /,$sentence;
@array=();
foreach $word(@sentence)
{
    chomp $word;
    my $flag= 0; #using a flag, I am sure there are PLENTY of ways better than this :)
    for $keys(keys %Drugs)
    {

        if($word=~/.*$keys$/i)#Changed this
        {
            $term="<$Drugs{$keys}>$word<$Drugs{$keys}>";
            push(@array,$term);
            $flag++;
        }
        elsif($word=~/.*$Drugs{$keys}$/i)
        {
            $term="<$Drugs{$keys}>$word<$Drugs{$keys}>";
            push(@array,$term);
            $flag++;
        }

    }
    push (@array,$word) if $flag==0;
}
foreach $Bio(@array)
  {
     print "$Bio\n";
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, this took care of the regular expression. I want to push the non matching elements into the same array, if I use a else loop, multiple entries are getting pushed in the array. How can I avoid multiple entries

Comment: I am not sure what you asking, can you post an "expected" result

Comment: added in the expected part, since the term Drug is not matched it will be untagged but should be pushed into the array